# php replace href by condition

Tags: php, replace

I try to replace href by condition:

```
http://www.sitea.com/vip:  => http://localhost/aaa?search=
http://www.sitea.com/      => http://localhost/bbb/ (without 'vip:')
http://www.siteb.com/      => http://localhost/ccc/
```

I use `strpos` for judge:

```
$str='<a href="http://www.sitea.com/vip:vp_14098">link A</a><a href="http://www.sitea.com/contact">link B</a><a href="http://www.siteb.com/player">link C</a>';
if(strpos($str,'www.sitea.com')!== false){
    if(strpos($str,'vip:')!== false){
        $str = str_replace('http://www.sitea.com/', 'http://localhost/aaa?search=',$str);
    }else{
        $str = str_replace('http://www.sitea.com/', 'http://localhost/bbb/',$str);
    }
}
if(strpos($str,'www.siteb.com')!== false){
    $str = str_replace('http://www.siteb.com/', 'http://localhost/ccc/',$str);
}
echo $str;
```

But this output:

```
<a href="http://localhost/aaa?search=vip:vp_14098">link A</a>
<a href="http://localhost/aaa?search=contact">link B</a>
<a href="http://localhost/ccc/player">link C</a>
```

The second link not replace as I wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy. You're decisions are based on the results of strpos applied to a string containing *all* the links. Because `$str` contains a link of the first type, the corresponding if-condition is always true. You can use a regular expression to address that problem, or if this isn't just a simplified example but your real world code, try this:

```
$str='<a href="http://www.sitea.com/vip:vp_14098">link A</a><a href="http://www.sitea.com/contact">link B</a><a href="http://www.siteb.com/player">link C</a>';
$str = str_replace('http://www.sitea.com/vip:', 'http://localhost/aaa?search=vip:',$str);
$str = str_replace('http://www.sitea.com/', 'http://localhost/bbb/',$str);
$str = str_replace('http://www.siteb.com/', 'http://localhost/ccc/',$str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: if there are more links in `$str` how to make a difference between `http://www.sitea.com/vip:` and `http://www.sitea.com/` , str_replace will replace from top to the end. thanks.

Comment: If you replace `http://www.sitea.com/vip:` first, those are gone from the string, right? So if you replace all occurrences of `http://www.sitea.com/` afterwards, those with `vip:` at the end won't be touched because they are already replaced by something else. I'm not quite sure if this answers your question, but otherwise you will need to clarify what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because all of your urls are in the same string, so as it goes through your code, it matches the "sitea.com" comparison, and then it matches the "vip:" comparison and then it goes into that and replaces all occurrences of "sitea" with your "aaa" replacement.  It never gets into the "bbb" replacement line because $str always contains "vip".

What you will need to do is split your $str into an array of urls and process each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to parse each url differently, and you are doing them all in the same string.  The str_replace is ALWAYS finding :vip, because it's in your entire string.

There will be a post here that will probably give you some regular expressions to use, but that is not my area of expertise.  Instead, I will offer you these changes to your code:

```
<?php
    $str='<a href="http://www.sitea.com/vip:vp_14098">link A</a><a href="http://www.sitea.com/contact">link B</a><a href="http://www.siteb.com/player">link C</a>';
    $str = str_replace('http://www.sitea.com/vip:', 'http://localhost/aaa?search=',$str);
    $str = str_replace('http://www.sitea.com/', 'http://localhost/bbb/',$str);
    $str = str_replace('http://www.siteb.com/', 'http://localhost/ccc/',$str);
    echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: if there are more links in `$str` how to make a difference between `http://www.sitea.com/vip:` and `http://www.sitea.com/` , should I use `preg_match` to make a judge instead of `strpos`?. thanks.